# How to split char pointer array into two char pointer arrays

Tags: arrays, c, string, split

My question is how can I split `argv` into two parts and store the parts in two variables.

I want my program to get parameters then a delimiter and then again parameters like this:

```
./program parameter1 parameter2 \: parameter3 parameter4
```

As you can see, the escaped '`:`' will act like a delimiter, cutting the array in two parts.
Now I want to get a `char *arr1[]` which will hold `parameter1` and `parameter2` and another `char *arr2[]` which will hold `parameter3` and `parameter4`. The parameters can be of different length.

How can I split `argv` and save the various parameters in two `char *[]`?
In the end I want to access (with my example in mind) `arr1[0]` and it should have the string `parameter1` inside it, and `arr1[1]` should have the string `parameter2` inside it.

Edit:
The problem lies in saving the parameters into the two different char *arr[]. I don't know how to do that, because I only know how to initialize an array with a value.

```
char *arr1[]; !error
char *arr1[10]; works, but what if I have more than 10 parameters?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to declare `arr1` and `arr2`? Do you know how to iterate over `argv`? Do you know how to compare strings? etc. Please show as much of the code as you know how to do as a [mre]. Otherwise it is difficult to know exactly which parts you can do and which part you need help with.

Comment: @kaylum I agree, I was not clear in asking my question. The problem lies in saving the parameters into the two different char *arr[]. I don't know how to do that, because I only know how to initialize an array with a value. Will edit!

Comment: @Oka Thank you for your comment, that is a great and better way to get the start of the second part of parameters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't! These are all pointers. Instead, use pointers - start pointer and end pointer or start pointer and count of element - to represent a "range" inside the source array.

```
char **arr1 = &argv[1];
char **arr1end = arr1;
while (*arr1end != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(*arr1end, ":") == 0) {
         break;
    }
    arr1end++;
}
if (arr1end == NULL) { /* handle error - user did not give : argument */ }
size_t arr1cnt = arr1end - arr1;
// Array arr1 has arr1cnt elements.

char **arr2 = arr1end + 1;
char **arr2end = arr2;
while (*arr2end != NULL) {
    ++arr2end;
}
size_t arr2cnt = arr2end - arr2;
// arr2cnt represents arguments after `:`.

for (size_t i = 0; i < arr1cnt; ++i) {
      printf("arr1[%zu]=%s\n", i, arr1[i]);
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < arr2cnt; ++i) {
      printf("arr2[%zu]=%s\n", i, arr2[i]);
}
```